# Override Magento Config

Tags: php, magento

I am looking for a good solution to override the Magento config without changing the default values.

For example, I want to override the "web/unsecure/base_skin_url" item in the core_config_data table without deleting the existing value. So if anywhere in the code this exact code is called:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('web/unsecure/base_skin_url');
```

It will find the config option I set and not the default one...

Thanks in advance!

Chuck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Magento reads its configuration values at runtime directly from the configuration object's tree structure, so you need to use the configuration object's native `setNode` method to change the values.  However, because of the way Magento [loads in scoped configuration](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_config) (self link), it's not as straight forward as it seems.

With current versions of Magento (and I believe, but have not tested, with older versions), you'll need to set the configuration value in the set of nodes for the current `store`.

Step one is getting the code for the currently set store.  You can do this programmatically with the following

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$code  = $store->getCode();
```

then, you can set a configuration value with the following call

```
$config = Mage::getConfig();
$config->setNode("stores/$code/web/unsecure/base_skin_url", 'value_to_set');
```

Keep in mind this all needs to happen **after** Magento has bootstrapped the configuration object. Also keep in mind there's a period of time where Magento will have a loaded configuration, but the store object will not be loaded.  If this is the case you will not be able to load the store code from the store object.

I did something similar in my [Pulse Storm Chaos module](http://alanstorm.com/magento_flat_collection_chaos).  If you're interested in working code it's on [Github](https://github.com/astorm/Chaos/blob/master/app/code/community/Pulsestorm/Chaos/Model/Entropy.php).

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation Alan! I can see how this would work well on per-store configuration but what if I want all the stores (and websites) to use my custom config option? In essence, I want my custom config option to be global...

Comment: @ChuckD Short Version: You'll need to add it for each store in the system (multiple calls).  When Magento creates the stores/store_code nodes it takes the default and website values into consideration. That way, the getStoreConfig method can always look at stores/store_code to find the right value.

Comment: Chuck, have you tried `$config->setNode("global/web/unsecure/base_skin_url", 'value_to_set');`? Just an idea, untested.

Answer (score 8):

Alan's answer is correct, but it doesn't care about the config cache. For example, if you call `Mage::getStoreConfig('web/unsecure/base_skin_url')` twice and change the value in between, the change has no effect.
To get around this issue, you should use `$store->setConfig('web/unsecure/base_skin_url', 'value_to_set')`. It does both: update the config cache and set the config node with Alan's method.

Comment: Thank you, it works! If someone is curious about how to get `$store` variable, mentioned in answer: `$store = Mage::app()->getStore();`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite some special config data, you can put it in app/etc/local.xml. But thats only useful for your own shop, not for public modules.

Heres a way to overwrite the `base_url` for development-purposes without altering the database.

```
<config>
...
    <stores>
        <default>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url>http://dev.myshop.com/</base_url>
                </unsecure>
                <secure>
                    <base_url>http://dev.myshop.com/</base_url>
                </secure>
            </web>
        </default>
        <admin>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url>http://dev.myshop.com/</base_url>
                </unsecure>
                <secure>
                    <base_url>http://dev.myshop.com/</base_url>
                </secure>
            </web>
        </admin>
    </stores>
...
</config>
```

Comment: You are rewriting value only for store with code "default" and admin. Also, after merging global configuration from all XML files Magento updates it from core_config_data table. If value in store scope was defined before it will override value from xml.

Comment: That was exactly what I was searching for. I missed out on the "<stores>" tag, but now it works :) I am not completely sure about the things that @PavelNovitsky said. But for a simple one store site, this should be sufficient.