# Magento: Change Config option without saving it

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

In my Magento module, I want to change a config option for just one run - the change should not be saved in the database.
It is only to change it with certain conditions during runtime, so that all subsequent core calls etc use that option.
I know you can use something like `Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig(...)`, but that actually saves the change in the database.
I'm using `Magento 1.5`.

Is that in any way possible?

Comment: Can't you do it simple ? get the old value, change it, run your script, save the old value

Comment: @dagfr No because I have to set it very early (right at App::run) and it has to span over all of magento's functionality.

Comment: You can also register the value you need (with Mage::register) and use this registry instead of the config everywhere you need it

Comment: @dagfr Which would imply I have to re-write half of Magento's core libraries. The value I need to change is the `{{base_url}}`.

Comment: Ok, and what is the purpose of changing this value ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Make magento accept a second url for the same shop - while still leaving the url untouched. But I found another workaround, I should remove this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to this:

```
Mage::getConfig()->setNode($path, $value);
```

See http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-programmatically-change-magentos-core-config-data/comment-page-1/#comment-9535

Answer (score 0):

Use `$store->setConfig('config_path', 'value_to_set')` to take in memory cache into account. Note that this is independent from the Magento config cache, but if you call `Mage::getStoreConfig()` twice with the same path it won't read the loaded XML structure but instead look it up in an array.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23384578/664108