# magento: save products without events?

Tags: magento

is it possible to save a product, but I don't want the events to be started.
I know events are not required because the update I do does not impact anything.
For instance I only update my own attributes or whatever.

Marius told me about this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($productIds, $attributes, $storeId);
```

which is great, so you don't even do a save, but I am just wondering if there is a means to skip events still calling the save() method (it might be helpful in some cases)

thanks,
Rod

Answer (score 0):

**Disabling the events on save may be a risky and harmful approach. I don't recommend it.**
But if you insist, I think you can achieve this by changing the config nodes with events at runtime.  [Here is how you can change a config node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12829802/2047249):

What you need to do is, before calling `$product->save()` get all nodes from the config that have events related to products: `global/events/catalog_product_save_before`, `global/events/catalog_product_save_after`...there may be others and insert the node `<type>disabled</type>` in them.  After the save is done remove the `type` node.

You can get all (global) observers for an event like this:

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/events/catalog_product_save_before');
```

Loop through the result and set the type to disabled.

Here is an example.
Let's say you have the event:

    
        
            
                
                    some/model_here
                    someAction

You need to do this:

```
Mage::getConfig()->setNode("global/events/catalog_product_save_before/observers/some_alias/type", 'disabled');
```

Note: other than the `global` area, events can be found in the `frontend` and `adminhtml` areas.