# How to set Magento store config data programmatically?

Tags: magento, configuration

To get store config data, I would use this code:

```
$data = Mage::getStoreConfig('my/path/whatever');
```

Now, how could I save to that node? I tried Alans suggestions from [Override Magento Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829669/override-magento-config), but it did not work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try following:

```
$value = "100";
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('my/path/whatever', $value);
```

OR

```
$resource = $this->getResourceModel();
$resource->saveConfig(rtrim('my/path/whatever', '/'), 1, 'default', 0);
```

Comment: Does this work for any configuration setting? I got a similar question in magento.exchange: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105634/how-to-export-import-features-settings-in-magento

Comment: first one is not working for me.  which of the arguments in the second example is the value that is being saved?

Answer (score 2):

Empire Solution is right but do remember to clean cache after it. So use something like

```
$value = "100";
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('my/path/whatever', $value);
Mage::getModel('core/config')->cleanCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a cases when i need change configuration and get changed configuration in the same runnig script. So the expresion doese not work for me:

```
$value = "100";
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('my/path/whatever', $value);
Mage::getModel('core/config')->cleanCache();
```

I looked at the Mage class and realized that $_config property is a static property and found Mage::reset() method. So fo my case work such expression:

```
$value = "300";
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('my/test/config', $value);
Mage::getModel('core/config')->cleanCache();

Mage::reset();
Mage::app();

$changed_data = Mage::getStoreConfig('my/test/config');
```

Comment: The following works pretty well: `Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('payment/modulename/order_status', 'pending');`. Without any additional reset/clear. My case was to set another status on order, other than that in the DB at the order creation time. The code was used in an observer.